# Split your emails using Gmail priority inbox

Tags: gmail

I tried to follow: [Split your emails using Gmail priority inbox - Android - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/186531?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1)...

However whenever I open Gmail app; by default, `Inbox` being displayed instead of `Important`, even though my `Inbox type` set `Priority Inbox` (tried `Important first` with same results).

Any advise? Otherwise, I'm getting bombarded with every single email that goes into my inbox (which is a lot)

Comment: Any luck using the answer below?

Comment: @aBochur nope, as it doesn't work like that, after short while it's still going back to regular Inbox instead of Priority(

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the Gmail app, I realized that they missed one detail in the link that you posted. Here's what you're supposed to do:

After switching to *priority inbox* following the instructions in the link, you have to then manually switch from the regular inbox, to the primary one. To do that, open the menu, and press on priority as shown below. After you do that, it will open it by default unless you switch back.

[image]